# FreeMarker if statement comparing two values

Tags: freemarker

I'm trying to compare two values

```
<#if user.cellPhone != changedUser.cellPhon>
    <br><span class="changes">*${changedUser.cellPhone}</span></#if>
```

I'm getting an error

```
freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException: The following has evaluated to null or missing:==> changeUser
```

Tip:

> If the failing expression is known to legally refer to something that's sometimes null or missing, either specify a default value like myOptionalVar!myDefault, or use <#if myOptionalVar??>when-present<#else>when-missing. (These only cover the last step of the expression; to cover the whole expression, use parenthesis: (myOptionalVar.foo)!myDefault, (myOptionalVar.foo)??

Comment: Why's there no `changedUser` (as the error message says)? Is that intended to happen? (Why doesn't the quoted tip help?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add null check to condition  `changedUser??`:

```
  <#if changedUser?? && user.cellPhone != changedUser.cellPhon>
```

Comment: Should be `changedUser??` instead of `changedUser != null`. FreeMarker 2 has no `null`.

Comment: Needed it to add ?? for both condition (user.cellPhone?? != changedUser.cellPhon??)